# share content with image on twitter from my site

Tags: twitter

I have a site that has some photos and I need to add to each of them twitter share button.
When user clicks that twitter share button, it should post to twitter the image, some text and
link to my site.

I tried to uploaded photos to twitrpix and put link to photos like this:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://mysite" data-text="http://twitrpix.com/c36at My test" >Tweet</a>
```

It works, but photos are not displayed in twitter until you click details. I would like photos to be
displayed all the time.

It looks like when I twit mamually adding photo using button with camera photo photo, the photo is
displayed all the time. How can I make it behave the same way when I share from my site?